# How to make precise the notion of "the multiset of roots of a polynomial function"?

Tags: polynomials, definition, multisets

A (real) polynomial *function* can be defined as a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the terms of $a$ are ultimately zero, and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i.$$

We can also define a *root-finding function* $\rho$ that takes polynomial functions to multisets. For any polynomial function $f$, define that $\rho(f)$ is the multiset of all $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. However, this last statement is hideously imprecise. It makes sense to speak of, "The *set* of all $x$ such that ---condition---," but the *multiset*?

How might one go about defining it rigorously?

Comment: The only imprecise part is defining multiplicities, which can be defined in various ways, e.g. by factoring $f$ or computing derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root multiset arises naturally from the factorization of the polynomial

$$\rm f(x) = (x-r)^j \cdots (x-s)^k g(x)\ \to\  \{\, j\cdot r,\:\ldots,\: k\cdot s\,\}$$

where $\rm\:g(x)\:$ has no roots over the coefficient ring.

More precisely, define $\rm\ e_r(f(x)) := max\{n\in\Bbb N\ :\ (x\!−\!r)^n\!\mid f(x)\,\ in\,\ \Bbb R[x]\}.\:$ Then the root multiset is  $\rm\ \{e_r(f)\cdot r\ :\ r\in roots(f)\},\:$ 
where $\rm\:n\cdot r\:$ denotes an element $\rm\:r\:$ of multiplicity 
$\rm\:n\:$ in a multiset.

Note that, over a domain, these linear factors are *unique*, being products of primes $\rm\,x-r.\:$ This uniqueness implies that the root multiset is well-defined. It also implies that any two (correct) root-finding algorithms will compute the same multiset of roots. The answer does not depend on what order the algorithm discovers the roots (as it generally does in *nonunique* factorization domains).

Comment: How would you cast your definition into more "rigorous" language? As in "for all polynomial functions $f$, define that $\rho(f)$ is the unique multiset such that..."

Comment: Said mapping *is* the definition. Factorizations are naturally multisets. It's analogous to multiset of primes in prime factorizations of integers.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your notation. Why is there no $\rho$ in the definition? And is your $\mathrm{f}$ the same as my $f$? EDIT: I understand the multiset notation, though.

Comment: Do you see how to map a prime factorization of an integer into its multiset of prime factors?

Comment: Yes, I understand the idea! I want to know how to state the idea precisely. For instance, in your notation, you appear to be mapping a real number $f(x)$ to a multiset $\{j\cdot r, \,...,k\cdot s\}$. Clearly, this isn't what you mean.

Comment: Define $\rm\ e_r(f) := max \{ n\in \Bbb N\ :\ (x\!-\!r)^n\!\mid f(x)\}.\:$ Then the root multiset is $\rm\ \{ e_r(f)\cdot r\ :\ r \in roots(f)\},\:$ where $\rm\:n\cdot r\:$ denotes an element $\rm\:r\:$ of multiplicity $\rm\:n\:$ in the multiset.

Comment: Now THAT'S the kind of answer I was looking for. If you change your answer to this, I can choose it.

Comment: I *have* to know. Why are you using `\rm` to make your maths upright text? It makes it harder to distinguish maths from regular text and it's not "how it's done" in English maths typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer but an alternative**.

Instead of multiset, a rigorous way to deal with roots of polynomial over
$\mathbb{C}$ with degree $n$ is to model the of roots of a polynomial as an element
in a quotient space of $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Two $n$-tuples $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ are identified together if one can find a permutation $\sigma$ of the coordinates such that $\lambda_j = \mu_{\sigma(j)}$ for $j = 1,\ldots,n$.

The space is usually denoted as $\mathbb{C}_{sym}^n$. It inherits a natural quotient topology from $\mathbb{C}^n$ and has a natural metric calling *optimal matching distance*:

> For $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n) \in \mathbb{C}_{sym}^n$, the optimal matching distance is defined as:
>   $$d(\lambda,\mu) = \min_{\sigma} \max_{1\le j \le n} |\lambda_j - \mu_{\sigma(j)}|$$ 
>   where $\sigma$ runs over the set of permutations of the coordinates.

The most important point is under this metric/topology, the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ depends continuously on its coefficients.

Comment: Does your first sentence imply that you think multisets are nonrigorous? If so, why?

Comment: @MathGems multiset is rigorous. However, it is more suited for problems that deal with algebraic aspect of roots. For problem that involve continuity, $\mathbb{C}_{sym}^n$ is a better choice.